# Autofac with Web API 2.2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

Simple test registration in global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //This allows interfaces etc to be provided as parameters to action methods
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new DiModelBinder();

        //Now call the method to initialise anything that is required before startup (which includes setting up DI)
        WebUiInitialise.InitialiseThis(this);


        var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceLayer.Startup.ServiceLayerModule());

        var container = builder.Build();
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Test apicontroller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public TestController(IListService service)
    {
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<AspNetUser> Users(IListService service)
    {
        return null;
        //return service.GetAll<AspNetUser>();
    }
}
```

When debugging into the TestController constructor, IListService service, has a value, but when debugging into the Users HttpGet method, it is null.

Is there a way to resolve the dependency (IListService service) for Web Api Controllers, for the get and post methods, and not just the constructor?

For MVC Controllers, the methods resolve, and not just the constructor.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: Can you try by registering type like this - `builder.RegisterType<ServiceLayer.Startup.ServiceLayerModule>().As<IListService>();`

Comment: Autofac does not seem to work for the apicontroller method Users.  IListService service is not resolved when debugging into the method.  I tried  builder.RegisterType<GenericServices.Services.Concrete.ListService>().As<GenericServices.IListService>();  that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Autofac to inject something into your Web API controller it needs to be either a constructor parameter or a public settable property.

Even in MVC, Autofac does not, by default, populate controller action parameters. It has some ability to do that if you also register the special Autofac action invoker into the pipeline, but, again, that's not part of the default behavior - it's opt-in.

That action invoker support is not present in the Web API integration. For Web API, you need to use standard IoC practices instead.